# Inlining whole CSS file for Homepage and Prefetching

Tags: html, css, prefetch

## Background

We are experimenting with inlining CSS into a site's `<head>` to cut down page load times. Because the CMS we use allows for very flexible content management, inlining only 'critical' CSS isn't an option, because we can't know at the point of compilation what markup will / won't be used (and therefore displayed 'above the fold') at a later date.

Therefore, we are looking into the option of inlining the *whole* contents of `main.css` file into just the homepage `<head>` then prefetching `main.css` so that it is available in the cache for when a user navigates to another page on the site.

This would cut down page load time for the most common entry point to a site, whilst still caching the CSS for any subsequent page visits.

## Questions

I guess I've got a couple of questions, but they feel intrinsically linked so I thought to include them both here, rather than splitting them up into separate SO questions.

1. Are there any drawbacks with inlining the whole contents of `main.css` into the homepage `<head>`? My main concern would have been file size, but when gzipped the difference with / without the inlined CSS is very small, and either way, the styles would have to be downloaded at some point, either in the html file or the CSS file.
2. When is the best point to prefetch the actual file? Really, the consideration is whether or not prefetch would at point of parsing trigger a synchronous request to the server, which would count towards the limit for parallel connections, thus potentially blocking other requests. If so, I guess the `<link>` should either live at the bottom of the document, or be written asynchronously to the DOM. If not, I think it makes most sense to live where the `<link rel="stylesheet">` would have been, in the `<head>`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Link_prefetching_FAQ

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr:**

Convert `main.css` into `base64` and add to the `<head>` of the main page. Then **add prefetch link** for `main.css` *right before* the body close tag `</body>`

---

This answer *may be* a bit **unorthodox** but, here goes.

**Yes, you can do exactly what you described; however, you will be downloading the CSS twice on your homepage.**

**Considerations**:

- *This will only work well if your CSS files is well written and is not heavy.*
- *It's a pain to maintain the CSS* because you will
  **have to repeat the whole process for every small change you want to
  make to your stylesheet**.

*Still interested?* Ok

1. Finalize your `main.css` file
2. **Compress and optimize** the `css` contents using any `css` cleaning tool
3. Save a copy of the `main.css` file somewhere
4. Convert the `main.css` file to `base64`
5. Save the `base64` string
6. Add the following to the `<head>` of your document

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="data:text/css;base64,###" />
   ```
7. Add the `base64` string for your `main.css` file in place of `"###"` **at
   the end of the code above**

---

This covers inlining the `CSS` on your homepage.

*If you do this correctly,*

You will be able to load your entire `css` for the homepage **without any additional requests**. *It will be a part of the homepage* `html`

**Consideration**:

- This chunk of `CSS` **will not be cached by browsers** **unless your
  server is configured to serve cached html pages**

  *Only then will it be cached as part of the `html` for the homepage.*
- It will only be cached for the homepage. **This `CSS` block is useless
  for any subsequent pages**

---

**Now, for the subsequent pages**

8. Locate the `main.css` file on your server
9. Add the `rel="prefetch"` link - *at the VERY bottom of your homepage* - linking to that file.

**This is what the html for the homepage should look like:**

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="data:text/css;base64,###" /> 
  /* stuff */ 
</head>
<body>
  /* stuff */
  <link rel="prefetch" href="main.css">
</body>
```

---

**Conclusion:**

If done correctly; browsers will:

1. Visit your homepage
2. Process the inline `css` for the homepage.
3. Process the content of your homepage and render it fully
4. `Prefetch` the **cache-able** `css` file **for subsequent pages**

---

**Bonus:**

**You can take this a step further** by changing any font files you have into `base64` and then in-lining those into the `main.css` file before converting it to `base64`

This will cut down the number of requests even further.

**Consideration:**

- Not all browsers support modern font files.
- in-lining different formats of the same font for different
  browsers - **(ttf + woff + svg) etc...** -  will not work because they will all be downloaded as opposed
  to them being served according to the browser capabilities
- I use this method and serve `.woff` only and it's supported by almost
  93% of browsers according to [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com)

---

**Final Words:**

- Make sure your server uses `Gzip`
- Make sure your `main.css` file is served **minified**.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer! Just a few things I feel I need to clarify before I feel I can accept: 1) What is the advantage of converting the contents of `main.css` to `base64` and including in a `<link>` tag over just including them in a `<style>` tag? 2) Why should the `<link rel="prefetch"...>` tag live at the very bottom of the body? Would it act as one of those parallel connections I mentioned? Btw, the inlining etc would happen as part of the 'build for web' process, so should be pretty straightforward to maintain, and minification / gzipping  is all handled already.